# Why does ((unsigned int)low + (unsigned int)high)) >> 1 work?

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search

I don't understand what is the relationship between

```
int mid = ((unsigned int)low + (unsigned int)high)) >> 1
```

and

```
int mid = low + (high - low) / 2
```

Why do they work as intended in such a way  they prevent overflow issue? I think that casting to unsigned type would ruin the result but seemingly not. Mathematically I can't get its explanation why they work.

The question is actually related to binary search. It is [the renown bug](https://ai.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html) not detected until 2006.

[image]

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning the word "average" somewhere, for searchability.

Comment: @j_random_hacker "midpoint" is the seo term you are looking for

Comment: The author of the article you link to says they learned of this issue in 2006, not that nobody detected it until 2006.

Comment: This fairly long-winded expression works for any signed integer values without overflow and rounds the midpoint towards zero: `int mid = a / 2 + b / 2 + ((a % 2 + b % 2 + 2) / 2 - 1);`. (I used `a` and `b` instead of `high` and `low` because the ordering doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 3):

```
int mid = ((unsigned int)low + (unsigned int)high)) >> 1
```

This only "works" if (1) you limit yourself to working with `int` indices, and (2) your C compiler implements the (in practice universal but not actually guaranteed-by-the-language-standard) behaviour of allowing `unsigned` types to repurpose the sign bit to represent more positive values: In this case, `unsigned` types have just over twice the maximum representable positive value as their corresponding signed type (you effectively get an extra bit to work with because there is no need to store the sign). That's enough here since you are only adding 2 `int`s, each of which can be at most `INT_MAX`, and `2 * INT_MAX < UINT_MAX`. This technique will overflow if you instead use `unsigned` indices and encounter a pair of indices above `INT_MAX`.

```
int mid = low + (high - low) / 2
```

This *always* works, regardless of the type. (E.g., if you changed `int` to `unsigned`, it would continue to work for all `unsigned` values of `high` and `low`.) That's because if we momentarily imagine that `int` could represent any integer, it's mathematically equivalent to the way it's usually written:

```
int mid = (low + high) / 2
```

Both expressions will compute the same value *if we have enough bits*, and the former never runs out of bits because none of the intermediate expressions (`high - low`, `(high - low) / 2`, `low + (high - low) / 2`) are larger than `high`, which we already know to be representable in an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The first version does not solve the issue completely.

The article you linked makes some assumptions which are not explicitely pointed out.
In the shown code `low`, `mid` and `high` are all of type `int` which is a signed type.
Also as they are used as index into an array, only positive values are valid.

Limiting us to positive values, the cast to `unsigned int` does not change the value at all. It merely allows us to use the MSB as well which we need in case of an `int` overflow. With an unsigned integer, the highest bit does not mean a negative value and when we shift it by 1, the sign and the value are as we expect.

Without these two constraints, your code would not work. As soon as `low` and `high` are already unsigned integers, you can run into same overflow problem again. (I know, C standard does not call it overflow for unsigned values but that does not solve the problem.) In this case the overflowing bit does not end up in the variable and after shifting you get a wrong value.

The second version does solve the issue in any case:
If you subtract 2 numbers which are both in range `0..INT_MAX` you will also get a result in that range. (Given the smaller is subtracted from the larger.)
From basic math we know that `low`+`mid` must also be in that range because `mid` is smaller than `high`.
So we cannot run into overflow issues here.

Comment: The C standard does not guarantee `unsigned int` has an additional value bit over `int`. C 2018 6.2.6.2 2 only guarantees it has at least as many value bits. It may use the `int`’s sign bit as a padding/parity bit. See [my comments on the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67583558/why-does-unsigned-intlow-unsigned-inthigh-1-work#comment119459155_67584046).

Answer (score 2):

Both work by making sure that allowed range is not exceeded, and take advantage of the fact that neither value can be negative.

Latter is simple: it uses substraction to make sure that value will never exceed value of `high`.

Former uses different technique: it bypasses the problem by increasing allowed range. If you add together two N-bit numbers, result is at most N+1 bits. We get that extra bit for using unsigned numbers which don't have a sign bit.

Note that bit-shift (`>> 1`) doesn't provide any extra value; you could as well use division (`/ 2`) because numbers are unsigned.

Comment: The C standard does not guarantee `unsigned int` has an additional value bit over `int`. C 2018 6.2.6.2 2 only guarantees it has at least as many value bits. It may use the `int`’s sign bit as a padding/parity bit. See [my comments on the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67583558/why-does-unsigned-intlow-unsigned-inthigh-1-work#comment119459155_67584046).

Answer (score 2):

They (only) work because both `low` and `high` are known to be at least 0.

```
((unsigned int)low + (unsigned int)high)) >> 1
```

Positive signed integers are always less than half the largest unsigned integer of the corresponding type, as unsigned gets an extra bit of range. If `low` or `high` could be negative, there could be "overflow"<sup>1</sup> in the unsigned addition.

```
low + (high - low) / 2
```

There can never be underflow in `high - low`, as that only occurs when `high` is negative. There can never be overflow, as that only occurs when `low` is negative. `result / 2` can never overflow or underflow, you always get a value closer to 0. Adding that back to `low` will never overflow, as the result is never more than `high`

1. Unsigned arithmetic doesn't overflow, as it is defined modulo 2<sup>N</sup>, where N is the number of bits. However you end up with a wrapped value, which is still incorrect to use as an index

Comment: Unsigned variables cannot overflow, they wrap around. And the reason why these were converted to unsigned is likely to dodge potential arithmetic right shift more than anything else.

Comment: The C language separates the terms. If you speak in terms of raw assembler then yes only overflows exist and they are well-defined, by having the corresponding status flag set when they happen.

Comment: Re “Positive signed integers are always less than half the largest unsigned integer”: I think you mean an `int` is always less than half the largest `unsigned int`, or a value in a signed integer type is always less than half the corresponding unsigned integer type. By itself “integer” is a mathematical entity with no bound; it is only when we consider types in C (or other programming language) that we are talking about bounded values. However, either way, this is not guaranteed by the C standard…

Comment: The C standard only requires the number of bits in the unsigned type corresponding to a signed integer type to have at least as many value bits as the signed type, per C 2018 6.2.6.2 2 (for *M* value bits in the signed type and *N* in the unsigned type, it says “*M* ≤ *N*”). It does not require it to have more. For example, `int` could have one sign bit and 31 value bits while `unsigned int` has one padding/parity bit and 31 value bits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil C++ defines signed integers and corresponding unsigned integers as having the same number of bits

Comment: @Caleth: The question is tagged C, not C++.

Answer (score 1):

When overflow is possible? In case both `low` and `high` are close to `INT_MAX`.

Consider byte size for simplicity.

If we add `0x7D` and `0x7F` (`125` and `127`), we get `0xFC = 0b11111100`.

If we interpret this value as signed, we have `-4`, if we interpret this value as unsigned, we have `252`.

Right shift for signed works as aritmetic shift `SAR`, which pads left part with sign bit, giving `0b11111110`, signed `-2` (note the same result as integer division by 2). Definitely we don't want such result for average of `125` and `127`.

Right shift for unsigned works as shift `SHR`, giving `0b01111110`, unsigned `126`.

So the first expression works in unsigned aritmetics until the final assignment, when result already lies in range of `INT_MAX`

Comment: Well, all sane compilers implement signed shift right as arithmetic shift right, but I believe it's technically implementation-defined.

Comment: The C standard says that signed overflow is undefined behavior so it's not sure the result of the add will be `0xFC`

Comment: @j_random_hacker "The value of E1 >> E2 is E1 / 2 (to the power) E2, rounded down. [ Note: E1 is right-shifted E2 bit positions. Right-shift on signed integral types is an arithmetic right shift, which performs sign-extension. — end note ]"

Comment: @Caleth: What's your source? 6.5.7/5 in [the draft C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says "The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of E1/2^{E2}. If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined."

Comment: that's from (draft) C++20

Comment: @Caleth: Interesting, but the question is tagged `c`. Do you have a source for that language?

Answer (score 0):

```
int mid = ((unsigned int)low + (unsigned int)high)) >> 1
```

**Does NOT work.** There is a `)` too much at the end.

I am not sure about the conversion of `high` here. But the compiler politely *suggests*:

> warning: suggest parentheses around '+' inside '>>'

```
9 |     int mid = (unsigned int) low + high >> 1;
  |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
```

This gives `((...)` pattern ant not `((...))`. With or without a second cast.

---

With unsigned cast and just the needed parens:

```
int mid  = ((unsigned)low + high) / 2;
int mid2 =  (unsigned)low + high >> 1;
```

This is without cast but a small trick (OP 2nd version):

```
int mid = low + (high - low) / 2
```

"Half the distance from low to high" is actually the concept, and not "average". This extra operation really is a good investment.

But this has a subtle (?!) bug:

```
int mid = low/2 + high/2;  //If both uneven --> 1 lost
```

---

`int` should be unsigned and bigger: `size_t` or `unsigned long`. Or just `long`: then we can talk about it again in 20 years.

---

K&R C book from 1988 has the same error in their own qsort taking int. The library one has size_t in prototype. This would fail with sloppy average formula only if somebody tries to sort a char array more than half the size than SIZE_MAX - which easily is ULONG_MAX.

Comment: It's a typo in the blog post `((unsigned int)low + (unsigned int)high) >> 1` is meant

Comment: Hah, I see, he was in the lets-make-it-clear mode from the above  `int mid = low + ((high - low) / 2)`.